# When to use UIMenuController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenucontroller

I've just found about `UIMenuController` but don't understand when to use it?
If I make `UITextField`, it looks like this text field already has build-in `UIMenuController` (because I can select, edit, etc.). So when to use this `UIMenuController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UIMenuController` anytime you are not satisfied with the standard capabilities provided by the iOS SDK.

Maybe you have a custom control you built and you want it to have a context menu. Or your `UITableViewCell`s should have a custom menu whose functionality goes beyond the standard implementation. (See example: http://captechconsulting.com/blog/john-szumski/getting-started-uimenucontroller-ios-5)

Every time the long-tap context menu does not provide sufficient functionality to your current use case, you implement you use your custom `UIMenuController`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Looks interesting to use it in UITableViewCell